# wp redirect 301 not working in wordpress page

Tags: plugins, redirect

http://www.mywebsite.com/my-page

on my wordpress page i have a form and i am redirecting my wordpress page to some other website after form submit

i have following code in my functions.php file for submitting form.

```
add_action('init', 'redirect');
function redirect(){
if(isset($_post['submit']))
{
    wp_redirect("www.google.com",301); exit();

}
}
```

but its not redirecting and showing 404 error and following url on submit
http://www.mywebsite.com/my-post/www.google.com

here i am using shortcode to display form on my wordpress page.

what is the reason? any clue?

Comment: Lowercase $_post might be your problem. Try $_POST instead. If that doesn't work, I'll work up an answer for you using a different route.

Comment: i am using $_POST in functions.php file. here i just wrote in hurry.

Comment: this is not the issue. i try this also. please try different route.

Comment: What about http:// in front of your URL?

Comment: Great.. 
Its just started working. thank you so much.
please post answer bellow. so you can take credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place http:// in front of the URL for wp_redirect to work properly.